# Unknown custom element - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, ecmascript-5

I'm currently using webpack with vuejs 2. I have a very basic component [Main.vue] that is rendered by vue-router and inside this component, I want to have another one [Information.vue]. For some reason, I can't render it properly.

components/test/Information.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
    TEST
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'information',
  props: {
    bleh: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

components/test/injex.js

```
export { default as Main } from './Main'
export { default as Information } from './Information'
```

components/test/Main.vue

```
<template>
    <information :bleh="{}" />
</template>

<script>
import { Information } from 'components/test'
export default {
  name: 'main',
  components: { Information  }
}
</script>
```

Any idea why I get the following error ?

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <information> - did you register
the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to
provide the "name" option
```

Comment: Is `Information` what you think it is? Do you see a vue component on `console.log(Information)` right after `import { Information } from 'components/test'`?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal Yes, I can console.log the component and actually see props. Also, doing this make the render possible. If I do not console.log(Information), the error is thrown.

Comment: You should do - import { information } from 'components/test'

Answer (score 4):

This is really old question but answering so that future visitors might get help:

Custom element shouldn't be self closed:

```
<information :bleh="{}" />
```

Make sure to use like this:

```
<information :bleh="{}"></information>
```

Thanks to [@connexo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744304/connexo) for the comment:

> Also for compliance with official web components, make sure you use a dashed tag like `<information-component ...></information-component>`

For those who get error with the following:

> Did you register the component correctly?

[Make sure to apply the name option in your component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154490/did-you-register-the-component-correctly-for-recursive-components-make-sure-to/49154700#49154700)

Comment: Also for compliance with official web components, make sure you use a dashed tag like `<information-component ...></information-component>`

Answer (score 0):

Try register component directly. I fixed my one by this.

```
Vue.component('Information', Information)
```