# Vue component not showing up in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component isn't showing up and I can't see where I went wrong, I'm hoping another set of eyes can point out where I went wrong. 
I'm running npm run watch and I've cleared my cache.

**My app.js**

```js
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('table-draggable', require('./components/TableDraggable.vue'));
Vue.component('category-index', require('./components/CategoryIndex.vue'));
Vue.component('active-checkbox', require('./components/ActiveCheckbox.vue'));
Vue.component('supplier-code-selection', require('./components/SupplierCodeSelection.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**My SupplierCodeSelection.vue**

```php
     <template>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">Supplier Code Selection Component</div>

                            <div class="card-body">
                                I'm an example component.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>

        <script>
            export default {
                mounted() {
                    console.log('Component mounted.')
                }
            }
        </script>
```

**my page that the vue is supposed to show**

```php
<div id="app">
    <supplier-code-selection></supplier-code-selection>
</div>
```

I also get this error in my console

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <supplier-code-selection> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

My composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Support/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

and my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "vue": "^2.5.7",
        "vuedraggable": "^2.16.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: i guess its because of name, hiphen(-). try to give name `supplierCodeSelection`

Comment: @KaranSadana - I just added the error to my question.

Comment: Show Laravel and Vue versions, please.

Comment: @KaranSadana - I gave it the name `supplierCodeSelection` and I still got the same problem

Comment: i have to confirm did you give name in `Vue.component('supplierCodeSelection', require('./components/SupplierCodeSelection.vue'));`
and also update to blade like `<supplierCodeSelection></supplierCodeSelection>`

Comment: @KaranSadana - yep I did and I even cleared my cache just in case.

Comment: @Nikki please check my updated answer

Comment: @Nikki try to give name in your component like `export deafult{
name : your-component-name,
mounted(){
//your mounted stuff
}}`
and use same name in other file

Comment: @Nikki Add Laravel and Vue versions to the question, please

Comment: @Styx - Sorry about this but what do you mean by laravel and vue versions? Do you want me to specify which code is vue and which is laravel?

Comment: @Nikki No, the versions of Laravel and Vue. Or just show your `composer.json` and `package.json`.

Comment: @Nikki did you try by giving name you can follow this like to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154490/did-you-register-the-component-correctly-for-recursive-components-make-sure-to hope its help

Comment: @Styx - I've updated my question to add both composer.json and package.json

Comment: @KaranSadana - Boussadjra Brahim suggested the same thing as you did and that still didn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is correct, but it seems that you forgot to include loading css/js files in your HTML.

Add this to the `<head>`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" />
<script defer src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

---

I also suggest using `npm run hot` (or `yarn hot`), that will add hot code reload.

Comment: Thank god. That worked. I always used `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>` and I never new about `npm run hot`

Comment: @Nikki Glad it helped. Using `asset()` just loads the asset, but using `mix()` loads compiled (by Laravel Mix) file. It will also support switching between dev/production environment, and many more. Here is the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix

Comment: I tried this. But oops. not working... mix doesn't load stylesheet and js

Comment: @KarthikSWOT Try to add leading slash before filepaths.

Comment: mine was a typo. Thanks

Comment: Dude after hours you saved my head from getting smashed to the wall.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code by adding the `default` property :

```
Vue.component('category-index', require('./components/CategoryIndex.vue').default);
```

or try this :

```
 ....
 import SupplierCodeSelection from './components/SupplierCodeSelection.vue'

  const app = new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       components:{'supplier-code-selection':SupplierCodeSelection } 
    });
```

and

```
     <script>
        export default {
          name:'supplier-code-selection',
            mounted() {
                console.log('Component mounted.')
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Still nothing I'm still getting the error `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <supplier-code-selection> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

Comment: did you add `name:'supplier-code-selection'` like i mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `.default`:

```
 Vue.component('supplier-code-selection', require('./components/SupplierCodeSelection.vue').default);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 10 using Vite:

In `vite.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    // The Vue plugin will re-write asset URLs, when referenced
                    // in Single File Components, to point to the Laravel web
                    // server. Setting this to `null` allows the Laravel plugin
                    // to instead re-write asset URLs to point to the Vite
                    // server instead.
                    base: null,
 
                    // The Vue plugin will parse absolute URLs and treat them
                    // as absolute paths to files on disk. Setting this to
                    // `false` will leave absolute URLs un-touched so they can
                    // reference assets in the public directory as expected.
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

In `resources/js/app.js`:

```js
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js';
import yourcomponent from './components/yourcomponent.vue';
const app = createApp({});
app.component('yourcomponent', yourcomponent);
app.mount('#app');
```

*Note: `/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js` seems to be required since `vue` alone won't work.*

In your blade file:

```html
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <yourcomponent />
</div>
```

Finally:

```bash
npm run build
```

or:

```bash
npm run dev
```

*Note: if you're using Laravel Sail, remember to prefix the npm command with `sail`.*

Answer (score -1):

hello)) maybe it too late but it can be usefull to someone else)). so i solved this kind of issue by this peace of cod  render: h => h(Main). Added it in new Vue({});

Answer (score -1):

Briefly, the common causes of this problem are as follows:

**1. If you don't include app.js file in the footer of page**

If you use laravel you can include it as you see:

```
<script defer src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

but if you use vite in development mode the best way is as follow:

```
@vite(['resources/js/app.js'])
```

**2. If you try to use your component out of the element that you select in Vuejs**

For example in Vuejs i select my app as div has app as id like you see

```
app.mount("#app");
```

so i have to put my code in element witch has app as id, as you see bellow (this is part of my master layout)

```
<div id="app" class="app">
@section('content')

@show
</div>
```

**3. If you don't convert you Vuejs to js app**

So you have to run "npm run dev" after any changes that's if you don't use vite

**4. If you have error in app.js file so you have to check your console in browser**

**5. If you don't declare your component**
Witch you can declare your component in old version in this way

```
 Vue.component('orders-table', require('./components/orders/_table.vue').default);
```

And in recent version in this way

```
import Orders from "./components/orders/_table.vue";
app.component("orders-table", Orders);
```

There are other errors but i think this is the common.